# JSON format leads to .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

With the current way strapi outputs a JSON I always get the error .map is not a function. It is a NEXT.JS Frontent. Could it be that this comes from the JSON not being output as an Array?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts &&
        posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // get games from the api
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/games");
  const posts = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

here I get: TypeError: posts.map is not a function

does anyone has a tip for a JS beginner how to fix that?

the JSON output is the following:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"attributes":{"title":"Guild Wars 2","createdAt":"2022-02-04T20:14:17.254Z","updatedAt":"2022-02-05T10:52:55.696Z","publishedAt":"2022-02-05T10:52:55.693Z","url":"https://www.guildwars2.com","description":"Guild Wars 2 is an online role-playing game with fast-paced action combat, a rich and detailed universe of stories, awe-inspiring landscapes to explore, two challenging player vs. player modes—and no subscription fees!","free":false,"feature_combat":"Fast-paced combat and choose from an arsenal of professions, weapons, and playstyles. Attack on the move, dodge and roll away from enemy blows, and come to your allies' rescue midbattle.","feature_world":"A beautifull designed, rich and detailed universe of stories, awe-inspiring landscapes to explore.","feature_quests":"No questgivers but an exploartion oriented roam around quest system with housands of stories that change based on the actions of players like you.","feature_grouping":"In the open world, you can team up with every player you meet—no grouping required! Also offeres Raids and dungeons for groups.","feature_usp":"Quick, furious matches between small groups of players in organized PvP or join hundreds of other players in the grand battles of World vs. World"}},{"id":2,"attributes":{"title":"Firefly Online","createdAt":"2022-02-05T11:01:39.549Z","updatedAt":"2022-02-05T11:04:40.562Z","publishedAt":"2022-02-05T11:04:40.558Z","url":"www.keepflying.com","description":"\nFACTS\nOS:\nSetting:\nSci-Fi\nGenre:\nRPG\nRelease Year:\n2014\nPayment Model:\nfree to play\nPVP:\nPay for features:\nItem Shop:\nMonthly fee:\nLanguage: ","free":null,"feature_combat":"Seek out adventures","feature_world":"Assume the role of a ship captain – create a crew and customize a ship","feature_quests":"Online role playing game based on Firefly, Joss Whedon’s cult-hit television series Firefly","feature_grouping":"Hire a crew","feature_usp":"Cross-platform player experience across devices"}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":1,"total":2}}}
```

Comment: If your build tool handles [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can simplify this and just do `posts?.data?.map?.(...) ?? null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `posts` is a JSON object and not an array that you can use the `map()` function with. Instead, you need to give the array to the `map()` function before you can pull out the titles.

To access the array of the JSON object, you can use `posts['data']`.

```
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts &&
        posts["data"].map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.attributes.title}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```